# Single Process Firefox (disable fork)

Tags: linux, firefox, plugins

I would like to run versions of Mozilla Firefox 3.6.5+ as a single process, just as it was in versions 3.6.3 and prior.

The reason is that, on Linux, I am running within proxychains - which doesn't bind to forked processes. Because the plugins in versions 3.6.5+ run in a forked process I can't use proxychains to redirect Flash streams.

Is there a setting in modern versions of Firefox that allow me to run plugins in the main process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `dom.ipc.plugins.enabled` setting(s) in `about:config`.

My understanding is that there is a default setting the applies to most plugins, plus additional plugin specific settings. Try setting them to false and see if that works for you.

See http://kb.mozillazine.org/Plugin-container_and_out-of-process_plugins for more info.

Comment: Fantastic answer!

Comment: Specifically: go to about:config and set all dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.* preferences to false